# Can't Get My Native Resolution

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, gpu

I've had no problems at all until yesterday.
I booted up  Ubuntu and the highest res. I can set is 1600x900 ( my monitor is 2560x1440 )
I used to have it set to native no problem however now it has disappeared ?
I have installed all the drivers but still no luck.
GPU is a 3060ti over display port.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the full results of running `xrandr` in a terminal. And can you confirm it's DisplayPort output on the PC and DisplayPort input on the monitor (no adaptors or anything).

Comment: Can you set the resolution in the system settings?

Comment: Yes display port out from PC, and into monitor ( works fine on Windows ) No adapters.
And No, I can only get upto  1600x900 in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I turned freesync off then back on again in my monitors menu, now  it's working fine